# C# - Cosmos DB bulk upsert

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, upsert, bulk

I have an Azure function triggered by a timer in which I want to update documents inside CosmosDB. Now I'm using the function `UpdateOneAsync` with option `IsUpsert = true` to make the update (or insert if the document doesn't exist).

However I'm doing the update operation inside a foreach loop, therefore an update operation is performed foreach item. How can I do a bulk update (upsert), performing just one operation after the foreach loop finishes?

Here it is my code right now:

```
foreach (var group in GetGroups(date, time, hour))
{
    dic = new MyDictionary<string>();

    //... some operations

    List<BsonElement> documents = new List<BsonElement>();
    documents.Add(new BsonElement("$inc", new BsonDocument(dic)));
    documents.Add(new BsonElement("$set", new BsonDocument(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "c", key }, { "d", date } })));

    var doc = clicksDoc.UpdateOneAsync(t => t["_id"] == "c-" + key + "-" + date, new BsonDocument(documents), new UpdateOptions() { IsUpsert = true }).Result;
}
```

Instead I'd like to perform just one update after the loop. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**2020 answer**

Bulk support has been added to the .NET SDK:
[Introducing Bulk support in the .NET SDK](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/introducing-bulk-support-in-the-net-sdk/)

To use it, first enable bulk execution when you create your client:

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClientBuilder(options.Value.ConnectionString)
    .WithConnectionModeDirect()
    .WithBulkExecution(true)
    .Build();
```

Then get your container as normal:

```
Container container = client.GetContainer("databaseName", "containerName");
```

Then do your bulk operation, e.g. upsert:

```
public async Task BulkUpsert(List<SomeItem> items)
{
    var concurrentTasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (SomeItem item in items)
    {
        concurrentTasks.Add(container.UpsertItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.PartitionKeyField)));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(concurrentTasks);
}
```

Comment: Accepting as answer as this can be helpful for the community. Thank you

Comment: not sure why, but this only worked if I wrapped the upsert in a Task.Run(), see below. The tasks would start to execute before calling the WhenAll.

`concurrentTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => container.UpsertItemAsync(item, new PartitionKey(item.PartitionKeyField))));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method **`BulkUpdateAsync`** from the **[`BulkExecutor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-dot-net)**,

```
List<UpdateItem> updateList = initialDocuments.Select(d =>
                new UpdateItem(
                    d.id,
                    d.AccountNumber,
                    new List<UpdateOperation> {
                        new SetUpdateOperation<string>(
                            "NewSimpleProperty", 
                            "New Property Value"),
                        new SetUpdateOperation<dynamic>(
                            "NewComplexProperty", 
                            new {
                                prop1 = "Hello",
                                prop2 = "World!"
                            }),
                        new UnsetUpdateOperation(nameof(FakeOrder.DocumentIndex)),
                    }))
                .ToList();

            var updateSetResult = BulkUpdatetDocuments(_database, _collection, updateList).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and

```
var executor = new BulkExecutor(_documentClient, collectionResource);
await executor.InitializeAsync();
return await executor.BulkUpdateAsync(updates);
```

**[SAMPLE](https://github.com/Toukiletoukan/CosmosDB-Bulk-Operations-.Net/blob/d5635f04fe973c2927fb175752a20684ed038076/CosmosDB.Playground/Program.cs#L172)**

Comment: Great. Unfortunately I'm using .NET Core in my azure function project and BulkExecutor isn't compatible with that .NET version. Microsoft Azure team has started working on the integration 2 month ago as you can see here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34559206-cosmos-db-bulkexecutor-for-net-core